# Which non-compact quaternion-Kähler spaces are Kähler?

Tags: reference-request, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds, quaternionic-geometry

The list of quaternion-Kähler *compact* *symmetric* spaces can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion-K%C3%A4hler_symmetric_space). I am curious to know which of the *non-compact* versions of these spaces are Kähler. If the answer is known also for *non-symmetric non-compact* quaternion-Kähler spaces (of negative scalar curvature), it'd be great to know this too.

Any information/reference about the specific cases is also welcome.

(cross-posted from math.stackexchange - [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4205253/which-non-compact-quaternion-k%C3%A4hler-spaces-are-k%C3%A4hler))

Comment: Being or not being Kaehler is a property you can read off from the holonomy group. So the duality between compact and non compact symmetric spaces answer the first part of your query.

Comment: About the second query the following is known: A (complete s.c.) non-symm. quaternionic Kaehler manifold is Kaehler if and only if it is already hyper-Kaehler. See e.g. page 10 in https://www2.math.hu-berlin.de/gradkoll/Cortes_vorlesung1_handout.pdf

Comment: @Holonomia So, regarding the first part - I gather that the symmetric spaces (whether compact or not) from the list are all s.c. and their holonomy is then just the isotropy group. Am I correct in concluding that in that list, only the spaces with the isotropy $Sp(p).Sp(1)$ and $E_7.Sp(1)$ are not Kähler?

Comment: Surely that spaces are not Kaehler. But there are others. You can get them just checking that $H$ has no 1 dimensional center e.g. the last of the list is not Kaehler.

Comment: @Holonomia Could you please explain why it should have some specific center? Isn't the isotropy being a subgroup of U(2p) enough for being Kähler?

Comment: I should say that the claim about the 1 dimensional center goes back to Elie Cartan's paper "Sur les domaines bornes homogenes de l'espace de n variables complexes". Indeed there he notices that irreducible non-compact symmetric spaces are realized as symmetric bounded domains. Moreover he observed that they can be realized as circled domains i.e. with the origin in his interior and invariant by the action of $e^{i \theta}$. So under the light of his own principle holonomy=isotropy this implies the claim about the center of the holonomy is not trivial.

Comment: You can also get the idea that the center of the holonomy is not trivial from one of the definitions of Kaehlerianess. Namely, a Riemannian manifold with a parallel complex estructure $J$. The paralelisms implies that $J$ commutes with the holonomy group. Then assuming that the holonomy acts irreducibly with a little work you get that either $J$ belongs to the Lie algebra of the holonomy group or the Ricci tensor vanish.

Comment: You can read and learn this facts and more in texts as Kobayashi-Nomizu or Helgason. Bounded symmetric domains can be constructed by using Jordan triple systems see e.g. Loos book "Bounded symmetric domains and Jordan pairs"

Comment: @Holonomia Thank you very much for the references. If I'm not mistaken, there are still several entries in this list that satisfy the condition on a center along with having an isotropy in $U(2p)$. However, unless there is some extra condition I'm missing, it seems to be in odds with [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0393044010002615), which (on p.2, paragraph right before Th. A) says that complex Grassmannian is the only Kähler entry in that list...

Comment: "several entries" ?  could you please list such several entries?

Comment: @Holonomia I'm sorry, my bad. I copied it with an error. Thanks again!